# How do I insert a "remove button" to every table row when inserting a new row using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would prefer to do it using javascript but if jQuery is easiest, then I will use that instead. I just don't understand jQuery very well. What I have currently for my HTML table is:

```
<table id = "liftTable" border="1" rules="rows">
<caption><b>Today's Workout</b></caption>
<tr>
 <th align="left" width="150">Lift Name</th>
 <th align="left" width="90">Weight (lbs)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Bench Press</td>
  <td>2000</td>
  <td><input name="btnRemoveItem" type="button" id="btnRemoveItem" value="Remove Lift" onclick="removeListItem(this)"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th align="left">Total:</th>
 <td class="sum">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That table has a sample already there showing how I want every new row to be set up. Here is my "Add Row" javascript:

```
function addTableRow(){
var iteration = 1;
var table = document.getElementById("liftTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length - 2;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Form1").value;
cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("numOfSets").value;
var bt = document.getElementById("btnRemoveItem");
cell3.appendChild(bt);
}
```

The biggest issue is when I try create "var bt = document.getElementById("btnRemoveItem");" and try to insert that into cell3. I don't really know how to accomplish this any other way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgot to include Form1 and numOfSets code, but those aren't absolutely necessary at the moment. I just want to know how to add the button to every row.

Comment: IDs are meant to be exclusive, so creating a new `removeButton` with a duplicate ID property could be giving you an issue. I would instead have `btnRemoveItem` be a class, and then query the row for an item with said class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers usually don't like it when you try to add the same *exact* element object to the DOM more than once in different places.

Try this instead and note that you may have to deal with multiple elements on the page which have the same element Id:

```
var bt = document.getElementById("btnRemoveItem").cloneNode();
```

- [MDN: Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)

Comment: That worked. The button is being cloned to every row and every row is removing perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Upvotes and accepts are the currency of this platform. Please and thank you!

Comment: Too low a level to upvote, I tried. Then accepting told me to wait 5 minutes. I found an issue when I remove the original row, the add row function can't find the original remove button to clone. I guess I can create the button element in the add row function, but I am not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: @Black Perhaps to begin, you should create a function which creates a new button each time using `document.createElement('button')`, assigns a unique identifier, and hitches your click-handler onto that element, instead of cloning the button from an existing button (which may later be removed).

Comment: Currently I have `var remove = document.createElement('button');`
`remove.id = 'removeButton';`
  `remove.innerHTML = 'Remove Lift';`
  `remove.onclick = removeListItem(this);` I am having trouble with `remove.onclick = removeListItem(this);` I don't know how to hitch the click-handler this way.

Comment: Use `remove.onclick = removeListItem;`. The `onclick` property is expected to be a function (note the missing parentheses), not the results of calling that function (which is what happens when you use the parentheses with a value). `removeListItem` will be called with the event object raised by the DOM element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45228/discussion-between-ryan-ransford-and-black)

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a new element with `document.createElement("input")`.  `cloneNode()` is already doing this anyway, but it gives you the flexibility to set the ID manually and to instantiate the input element without regard for whether or not there are any live examples in the DOM currently.  That's vanilla JS.  jQuery just has you wrap a `$()` around that if memory serves, and that only allows you to use jQuery to alter it and insert it instead of vanilla JS.

Comment: I tried doing 
var bt = document.createElement("button");
bt.id = btn1;
bt.value = Remove Item;
I don't know how to link the button to the removeListItem() javascript function

Comment: You have two options.  You can either set `bt.onclick` to `removeListItem(this)` or you can use `bt.addEventListener('click',removeListItem)`.  If you use the second option, be aware that Javascript will pass in the EVENT rather than the element, so you'll need to reference the `.target` property of your parameter.